# Android Leak Canary 2 fails to dump heap

Tags: android, leakcanary

i am trying to implement LeakCanary2 into my project to detect memory leaks but it constantly fails.

```
2020-07-03 19:37:41.834 17761-17799/com.example.projects D/LeakCanary: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission not granted, ignoring
2020-07-03 19:37:47.912 17761-17799/com.example.projects D/LeakCanary: Dumped heap file is 0 byte length
2020-07-03 19:37:47.914 17761-17799/com.example.projects D/LeakCanary: Failed to dump heap, will retry in 5000 ms
2020-07-03 19:37:47.914 17761-17799/com.example.projects D/LeakCanary: Rescheduling check for retained objects in 5000ms because failed to dump heap
2020-07-03 19:37:53.206 17761-17799/com.example.projects D/LeakCanary: Check for retained objects found 6 objects, dumping the heap
2020-07-03 19:37:53.214 17761-17799/com.example.projects D/LeakCanary: Removing 1 heap dumps
2020-07-03 19:37:53.222 17761-17799/com.example.projects D/LeakCanary: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission not granted, ignoring
```

and it goes on forever in a infinite loop.
If i grant the write external storage permission manually it is still not working.

Dependency

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.4'
```

Testing on a Moto G7.
When testing on an Emulator, it works as expected.

Comment: Suddenly everything is working as expected, I don't know what was wrong because I changed nothing and now it's working.

Comment: Super strange. Just bought a Moto G7 for testing an app recently, and can confirm - this is happening to me as well.

Comment: I have this problem with the MOTO E6. Not even Android Studio can dump the heap. Did anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: I have a Moto g pure and having the same issue.